# C# insert image on word template different image size depending on office version

Tags: c#, ms-word

I have a C# windows form in .Net framework 4.0, and I'm adding an image to a word template (bookmark).
I'm facing a situation where, depending on the Office version installed on the machine where I run the application, the image is rendered in different sizes. On Word 2010 it works like a charm, but on recent versions such as on Word 365 the image is smaller.

I'm just using the following code:

```
Word.Document doc = null;
            string filePath = "C:\myImage.png";

            string base64bytes = "My image base64 string";

            var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64bytes);

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
            {
                using (System.Drawing.Image imgToResize = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms))
                {
                    using (Image finalImg = new Bitmap(imgToResize, new Size(150, 150)))
                    {
                        finalImg.Save(filePath, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                    }
                }
            }
            document.Bookmarks["MyBookmarkName"].Range.InlineShapes.AddPicture(filePath, true, false);
```

Is there anything else I can do? Or any command or thing where I can ensure the image stays the same size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging for a while, found out that it was actually a different behavior between Office versions.

Had to check office version and based on it, set the image size before rendering.

But now and then, this happens, not always, not always on the same document, but happens:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1066): Command failed
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range.PasteSpecial(Object& IconIndex, Object& Link, Object& Placement, Object& DisplayAsIcon, Object& DataType, 
Object& IconFileName, Object& IconLabel)
```

The code:

```
string htmlTable = GetDataHtml(data, useGrouping);
            HtmlFragment.CopyToClipboard(htmlTable);

            object missing = Type.Missing;
            object pasteHtml = Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML;
            view.Bookmarks[bookmarkName].Range.PasteSpecial(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, Word.WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML, ref missing, ref missing);
```

Don't see anything strange here, and if it runs on a machine with Office 2010, it works like a charm.
Has anyone ever had this situation?

Comment: Just tried to replace this piece with saving the HTML as local file, and instead of PasteSpecial InsertFile. It seems to work ok, but then later I have another place where I really need to copy-paste and then paste fails again. is this incompatible with Word 2016 somehow but not always?

Comment: Just overcome the second issue, by replacing regular copy-paste with setting FormattedText from a bookmark to another. Working like a charm now